# Django Query to Aggregate the Sum for Matching Instances in the Same Field

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django (2.1) model:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sales= models.DecimalField(max_digits=25)
```

I would like to receive the sum of all sales for each different `product_name` instance that is the same.

For example, I have the following sales by `product_name`:

- DVDs = 6.00
- DVDs = 6.00
- Books = 14.00
- Books = 6.00
- Magazines = 4.00
- Magazines = 4.00

I can use `Sales.objects.aggregate(sales=Sum('sales'))` to get the total aggregate of all sales instances combined but how can I get the aggregate for `product_name` separately; i.e. Books ($20.00), DVDs ($12.00), Magazines ($8.00)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `.annotate` for this in combination with `.values`:

```
Sales.objects.values(
    'product_name'
).annotate(
    total_sales=Sum('sales')
).order_by('product_name')
```

Note that `product_name` is a `ForeignKey`, so we will get the id of the `Product` object, like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'product_name': 1, 'total_sales': 12.00 },
    {'product_name': 2, 'total_sales': 20.00 },
    {'product_name': 3, 'total_sales': 8.00 } ]>
```

Therefore I think you are probably more interested in querying with the `Product` object instead, something like:

```
Product,objects.values(
    'name'
).annotate(
    total_sales=Sum('sales__sales')
).order_by('name')
```

Which then produces:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'name': 'Books', 'total_sales': 20.00 },
    {'name': 'DVDs', 'total_sales': 12.00 },
    {'name': 'Magazines', 'total_sales': 8.00 } ]>
```

These are thus `QuerySet`s that contain dictionaries: each dictionary has two keys: `'name'` and `total_sales'`, and we can thus iterate over the dictionaries and process the key-value pairs.

We used `total_sales` since my experience is that naming the aggregate the same as another field typically results in some problems. First of all, it is not really clear that this is different from the `sales` field. Furthermore in some versions of Django this could result in invalid queries.

> **Note**: since a `ForeignKey` refers to an object of the related model. I advise to rename `product_name` to just `product`.

Comment: Thanks, Willem! Thank you for the answer- this is exactly what I needed. I also appreciate the advice.