# django queryset values not merging

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339193/6551200)

i have this model

```
class PortfolioExchangeTransaction(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name=_('Creator'))
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name=_('Create Time'))
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                  verbose_name=_('Portfolio'), related_name='exchange_transaction')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=Transaction_TYPE, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Type'))
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(BorseExchange, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name=_('Exchange'))
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_('Count'))
```

i want to sum count of all PortfolioExchangeTransaction per exchange

so i want sum similar records queryset per exchange as below code:

```
result = PortfolioExchangeTransaction.objects.all().values('exchange')
```

and i was hopping get something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 512}, {'exchageid': 248}, {'exchageid': 940}]>
```

but with values i got like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 512}, {'exchageid': 248}, {'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 940}, {'exchageid': 591}, {'exchageid': 248}, {'exchageid': 248}]>
```

## Updated

i want use annotate after abow:

```
result.annotate(sum_count=Sum('count', output_field=BigIntegerField()))
```

so i can't use distinct because giving this :

```
NotImplementedError('annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.')
```

how fix this?

Comment: some times `values()` not merging. can fix it by using `order_by()` before `values()`. notice: `order_by` and `values` must be on same field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) here:

```
PortfolioExchangeTransaction.objects.all().values('exchange').distinct()
```

### Update

Use `GROUP BY` here:

```
result = PortfolioExchangeTransaction.objects.values('exchange').annotate(sum=Sum('count')).values('exchange', 'sum')
```

Comment: distinct will block annotate and order_by. other solution?